# ASP.Net button not posting back under one set of circumstances

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

This has got to be the oddest error I have come across. I've created a template website, which contains a logon page. If you go directly to the logon page on the first load, the button does not postback, in fact it does nothing, just sits there and looks blankly at you. However, if you visit any other page first and get redirected back (because the individual hasn't logged on yet), it works fine.

This happens on IE, but I haven't tried on other browsers as this is part of a intranet and our system only uses IE8. I've also tried setting `UseSubmitBehaviour` and `CausesValidation` to false, but that has no effect.

I haven't posted all the code, as there are several pages involved, so I have put a basic description of the pages involved

**Master Page**

Normal master page, provides general layout and styling

**BasePage**

All pages within the application inherit this page. Ensures the correct theme/branding is applied according to the user's settings. Also checks to ensure the user is logged on and for particular pages it will redirect them back to the logon page if the user is unknown.

**Simplelogon.aspx**

A page just to handle the logon process. Code below

ASPX File

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upContainer" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pLogon" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="width: 400px; height: 180px; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-top: -100px; margin-left: -210px; position: fixed; z-index: 101; background-color: #eee; padding: 0px; border: 2px solid #000; text-align: center; padding: 10px;">
                    <span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 18pt">Welcome</span>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center"><b>User ID</b></td>
                            <td align="center"><b>Password</b></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="userID" runat="server" TextMode="SingleLine" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1"></asp:TextBox><br />
                                <span style="font-size: 8pt">&nbsp;</span>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1"></asp:TextBox> <br /> 
                                <a href="userReset.aspx" style="font-size: 8pt">[Forgot Password]</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRememberMe" runat="server" Text="Remember Me" /><br />
                                <asp:Button ID="logon" runat="server" Text="Logon" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <asp:Literal ID="litLogonMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

                    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 5px; font-size: 8pt; margin-top: -90px; display: block;">
                        <a href="UserRegister.aspx">[register]</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

VB page extract

```
    Private Sub logon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles logon.Click
    If Not (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userID.Text) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text)) Then
        Dim sqlParameters As New List(Of SqlClient.SqlParameter)
        SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParameters, "@PUID", userID.Text)
        Dim salt As String = SQLDB.fetchSingleValue("SELECT salt FROM Users WHERE PUID = @PUID", adminDB, sqlParameters)
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT UserID FROM WebApplication A INNER JOIN Permissions P ON A.ApplicationID = P.FkApplication INNER JOIN Users U ON P.FkUser = U.UserID WHERE PUID = @PUID AND Password2 = @Password AND ((A.ApplicationCode = @AppCode AND P.Locked = 0) OR U.AppsDev = 1)"
        Dim rP As String = varSession("ReturnPath")
        Dim appCode As String
        If fqAppPath.IndexOf("localhost") = -1 Then
            appCode = varSession("CallingApplication", "Global")
        Else
            appCode = SiteCode
        End If
        sqlParameters.Clear()
        SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParameters, "@PUID", userID.Text)
        SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParameters, "@Password", fetchHash(password.Text, salt))
        SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParameters, "@AppCode", appCode)
        Dim result As String = SQLDB.fetchSingleValue(strSQL, adminDB, sqlParameters)

        If IsNumeric(result) Then
            varSession("UserName", "Global") = userID.Text
            varSession("UserID", "Global") = result
            strSQL = "SELECT AppsDev, PasswordExpires FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID"
            sqlParameters.Clear()
            SQLDB.addParameterToList(sqlParameters, "@UserID", result)
            Dim dt As DataTable = SQLDB.fetchMultipleValues(strSQL, adminDB, sqlParameters)
            If Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows(0).Item("AppsDev")) Then
                varSession("AppsDev", "Global") = True
            Else
                varSession("AppsDev", "Global") = False
            End If

            Dim sql As String = ""
            Dim myCookies As New GenericCookie()

            myCookies.setRememberMeCookie(cbRememberMe.Checked)
            myCookies.SetCookies(varSession("UserID", "Global"), varSession("UserName", "Global"))
            sql = "UPDATE Permissions SET LastUsed = current_timestamp WHERE FkUser = " & varSession("UserID", "Global") & " AND FkApplication IN (SELECT ApplicationID FROM WebApplication WHERE ApplicationCode = '" & appCode & "')"
            SQLDB.executeSqlCUD(sql, adminDB)

            If dt.Rows(0).Item("PasswordExpires") < Now Then
                Dim newPassword As String = generatePassword()
                Dim newSalt As String = generatePassword()
                Dim newHash As String = fetchHash(newPassword, newSalt)
                Dim newDate As DateTime = Now.AddMonths(6)

                sql = "UPDATE Users (Password2, Salt, PasswordExpires, PasswordExpired) VALUES ('" & newHash & "', '" & newSalt & "', '" & newDate & "', 0) WHERE UserID = '" & result
                SQLDB.executeSqlCUD(sql, adminDB)

                litNewPassword.Text = newPassword
                pLogon.Visible = False
                pChangePassword.Visible = True

            Else

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(rP) Then
                    Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
                Else
                    Response.Redirect(rP)
                End If
            End If

        Else
            password.Text = Nothing
            litLogonMessage.Text = "Unable to verify your credentials.<br />Please check your User ID and re-enter your password to try again"
            varSession("FailedLogons", "Global") = varSession("FailedLogons", "Global") + 1
            If varSession("FailedLogons", "Global") > 3 Then
                Response.Redirect("/accessdenied.aspx"))
            End If
        End If
    Else
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(userID.Text) Then
            userID.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            userID.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            userID.BorderWidth = 2
        Else
            userID.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Silver
            userID.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            userID.BorderWidth = 1
        End If
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text) Then
            password.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            password.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            password.BorderWidth = 2
        Else
            password.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Silver
            password.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid
            password.BorderWidth = 1
        End If
        litLogonMessage.Text = "<span style=""color: #f00"">Please enter your User ID <b>and</b> password to continue</span>"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What server version is it running on? Which .NET version is it?

Comment: Framework is 4.0, not sure on the IIS version as I don't see it. I only publish it to it. But I have tried it on 4 different servers and it acts in the same way.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the event / javascript log? Outside the validator issues which you've tried yourself from your description - such issues are often a symptom of multiple forms, something in a basepage/usercontrol blocking,  or issues raising the postback event itself which can give a script error. Could there be some difference in binding between the "normal" and "redirect" attempt?

Comment: No error messages. All it does is the button visually does the depress thing, then just sits there and does nothing. There is only one form (I had already checked, but forgot to mention). I can't see there being any difference between normal and redirect. All basepage does is response.redirect the user to simplelogon.aspx if they are not logged on.

Comment: Are you certain it's not posting back (i.e. have you put a breakpoint on Page_Load)?

The reason I ask, you're using an updatepanel which may give no obvious visible page refresh. Also, why have 2 nested updatepanels?

Comment: Thats not the complete page, there are other elements to it, but I had strip them out, but they won't be affecting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was, I was basically shooting myself in the foot. The page was posting back, but because of some code deeper in the system it was going straight through and doing nothing.

Thanks to those who helped in putting me on the right path

Comment: In the future, you can find this out fairly quickly by setting a breakpoint in your code and stepping through it.

Comment: Normally I would, but in debug mode it was working fine, it wasn't until I had it on a server that this issue cropped its head up and had a few of us scratching our heads.

Comment: Then either add logging or use the [remote debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx).